# Copy field from child to parent

Tags: apex, child-to-parent

Can you help me, on how to continue copying from Participant to Account wherein fields are the Year and Goal, I am struggling in last part which is the year and goal this is as follows  child is Participation > Personnel > Acccount, I got the ID's of the two

```
public class AccountParticipateTriggerHandler {
    public void CopytoAccount(List<Participation__c> partic) {
        List<id> parentIDstoUpdate = new list<id>();
        Map<Id,Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>();
        Map<Id, Set<String>> mapParentIdtoString = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();
        Map<Id, Set<String>> mapParticipation = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();

        string str;

        for (Participation__c co : partic) {
            parentIDstoUpdate.add(co.AFName__c); 
            system.debug('parentIDstoUpdate' + parentIDstoUpdate);
        }

        for (Participation__c co: [
            SELECT id,Year__c, Goals__c 
            FROM Participation__c 
            WHERE AFName__c in : parentIDstoUpdate
       ]) {
            system.debug('oppco' + co);

            if (!mapParentIdtoString.containsKey(co.AFName__c)){
                mapParentIdtoString.put(co.AFName__c, new Set<String>());
            }

            mapParentIdtoString.get(co.AFName__c);
        }

        List<Personnel__c > personnels = [
            SELECT id, parentAccount__c  
            FROM Personnel__c 
            SHERE ID =: parentIDstoUpdate
        ];

        for (Personnel__c pers: personnels){
            system.debug('personnels' + pers);

            if (!mapParticipation.containsKey(pers.parentAccount__c )){
                mapParticipation.put(
                    pers.parentAccount__c, new Set<String>()
                );
            }

            mapParticipation.get(pers.parentAccount__c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to take the values of the `year__c` and `goal__c` field from the `participation__c` record through the `personnel__c` record and put it into a field on the parent `account` record.

I'm assuming the field name on account matches the field name on the Participation record:

```
public class AccountParticipateTriggerHandler {
    public void CopytoAccount(List<Participation__c> partic) {
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>()

        partic = [
            SELECT Id, Year__c, Goal__c, AFName__r.ParentAccount__c
            FROM Participation__c
            WHERE Id IN :partic
        ];

        for (Participation__c p : partic) {
            Account a = new Account(
                Id = p.AFName__r.ParentAccount__c,
                Year__c = p.Year__c,
                Goal__c = p.Goal__c
            );

            accountsToUpdate.add(a);
        }

        update accountsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Make sure this runs in your after trigger.

Comment: I am having an error with update accountsToUpdate(); it says Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void accountsToUpdate() from the type AccountParticipateTriggerHandler at line 19 column 16

Comment: Sorry updated the answer. Thats what happens when you type too fast :P

Comment: Thank you so much! I learn something new from you, based from my long code T_T

Comment: My first draft was pretty long too but once I had something that seemed functional I reduced it to as simple as I could get it. I think that's a good rule for everyone to follow.